# Login Problem with IE 9 only on all machines

Tags: 2011

I am having domain log in problem with Internet explorer 9 only, I have Tridion 2011 sp1.
If i log in with admin account it works well (admin means local admin, its not the domain account) but doesn't work with domain accounts, I have checked in other version of IE (8 and 10), all works well. Firefox and Chrome works well.

My team members also facing same problem with IE 9 only. Works with local admin account only, doesn't work with domain account.

Any thing i need to configure for IE 9 only?

Comment: "Doesn't work" could be several things.  It would be helpful if you provide the exact error message you're getting.  Also, is there any portal or SSO providers such as SiteMinder in place?

Answer (score 4):

Follow the instructions on [SDL Live Content to configure your browser](http://sdllivecontent.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL_Tridion_2011_SPONE/task_43B1609144D94562A394BB51FAC884B9) ([requires login](http://docportal.sdl.com/sdltridion)). The biggest "gotcha" is not setting the CMS url under the Local intranet zone.

You may also want to confirm your IIS Authentication settings for the Content Manager, the details are described under [Content Manager Security](http://sdllivecontent.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL_Tridion_2011_SPONE/concept_AD97946C6E47453E92C57B802BF903E6) and depend on your specific setup.

Comment: I checked everything and that's why it is working on all browsers including IE 8 and 10 but problem is with IE 9 only, I can access my CMS through local admin account but can't access through domain account. My VM where i have installed Tridion has IE 10 but my host machine has IE 9.